# Circle difference in contour integral

Tags: contour-integration

Let's say I am integrating a function over $|z| = 1$ and $|z-1| = 1$, is there any difference? I think the answer for both cases will be same, as in both cases,

$$
z = \exp^{i\Theta}
$$
and
$$
dz = i \exp^{i\Theta} d\Theta
$$

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: For $|z-1|=1$, $z=1+e^{i\phi}\ne e^{i\phi}$.

Comment: Thanks @Dr.MV, I thought the center won't be included in the equation of z. This solves my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\int\frac{dz}{z+\frac 1 2}
$$

Integrated over $|z-1|=1$, this is $0$, since it is holomorphic everywhere on and inside that circle.  Integrated over $|z|=1$, running counterclockwise, this is $2\pi i$, because of its pole inside that circle.

Comment: Why will it be $2\pi i$?

Comment: Ok got it now, Cauchy integral formula. Thanks.